# I am using dynamic panels. I have used "collapse" buttons. The problem is, the collapse button is working only for the first panel

Tags: angularjs, dynamic, angular-ui-bootstrap, panel

I am using dynamic panels. For now, I have hard coded the data in my JS file. I have used a collapse button. The issue is, the collapse button works fine only for the first panel. Though the collapse button appears on the other panels, it is not working.

Can someone please help me?

Also, i have used a custom directive for using dynamic panels.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you used same id in data-target.
You should consider unique target id and target for each item.I suggest use $index of ng-repeat also it is better always use track by for ng-repeat in your case track by $index
Edited code :

```
    <div class="text-center">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-default collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" 
           data-target="#demo-{{$index}}">
        VIEW DETAILS
       </button>
    </div>
    <div id="demo-{{$index}}" class="collapse">
        Lorem ipsum 
    </div>
```

If the problem not solved please prepare a plunker to be more specific.